# how to find mean average precision of object detection algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, precision-recall, object-detection, average-precision

To start with, I would like to mention another question which was asked in a better way. But my problem differs.
[pseudo code for the algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260430/average-precision-in-object-detection?newreg=d4d328d0ae1644d1b58e9fe6107d576f)

I have four different object detection algorithms which I have gathered from Internet. I can share one of them. My dataset is really simple one. I would like to first assign Ground Truth bounding box to my images and then compute IOU and lastly compute the mean average precision of the models in python. Kindly share python code with me. Which I should integrate in the algorithms to get the results.

[COVID-19: Face Mask Detector with OpenCV, Keras/TensorFlow, and Deep Learning](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/04/covid-19-face-mask-detector-with-opencv-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/)

I would like to get complete guidance on this.

Comment: See mean-average-precision library here: [https://pypi.org/project/mean-average-precision/](https://pypi.org/project/mean-average-precision/)